# How could I know whether a size_t as a parameter is valid in a function?

Tags: c++

Type size_t is always positive even passing a negative number to it. The problem is that how could I know it is valid.

Comment: What's you definition of "valid"?

Comment: If you want to have ability to pass an invalid one, you can also add a boolean parameter that states whether there is an error or no, or also you can add an enum error

Comment: Did you consider enabling the warnings? That way you get informed when implicit lossy conversion is performed.

Comment: If the question is that you want to pass -1 as invalid, use static_cast<size_t>(-1). Preferably the definition is in one place (e.g. constexpr size_t g_nInvalid = static_cast<size_t>(-1);).

Comment: The C11 (not C++) standard even introduces a type [rsize_t](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.4) and a macro RSIZE_MAX specially for finding errors like passing negative numbers to function that expect `size_t` argument.

Comment: If a signed number was passed then the compiler will warn you, but you simply need to check the valid range. For example `if(n > 4 && n < 12) ...`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Probably the best answer so far. But why is it in the comments section?

Comment: C++ doesn't have RSIZE_MAX . Probably the best answer would be to create an interface from C file compiled using C11 to C++ that exports RSIZE_MAX using some kind of function. Or we can query the OS for available memory (`/proc/mem` ?) and limit size_t with that.

Comment: The reverse situation is worse because converting from `unsigned` to `signed` can trigger implementation defined behavior. At least this way the behavior is predictable across platforms.

Comment: You can prevent narrow conversion in C++11 using {...} . If you use gcc, add parameter -Wnarrowing and it will warm you if you try to do something like this: size_t val={-5};

Answer (score 2):

You can crank up your warnings, so that the compiler rejects attempts to initialise unsigned values from signed values. Then it's impossible to pass a negative value to a `size_t`.

E.g. [in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) you pass `-Wsign-conversion -Werror` as additional command line arguments

Comment: @RichardCritten ah, the docs (and a SO search) are misleading, fixed

Comment: Thanks for the fix going add that switch to my paranoid build test - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell. But suppose your function is `foo(size_t)`. What you *can* do is introduce a suite of overloads instead.

```
foo(const size_t&) // ToDo - consider replacing with `const int&`, `const long&` etc.

foo(const int&)
```

and so on. The `const` references prevent implicit conversion to a `size_t` at a calling site. Then you can inspect the sign of a `signed` value to assert validity.

Comment: The problem with this will be with some calls of the form `foo(expr)` where `expr` is an expression that gives a result of type `int`.   Expressions involving `int` operands and `int` result can have undefined behaviour, for example, if overflow occurs.   Undefined behaviour cannot be reliably detected, and the value passed to `foo()` will be indeterminate.

Comment: `foo(const int &) = delete` fixes the UB problem

Comment: This is okay for one parameter, but with several wouldn't the number of overloads rise exponentially?

Comment: @Galik you can write a `unsigned_wrapper` that has all but the `unsigned_wrapper(unsigned)` constructors deleted and then instead of taking `unsigned` you take `unsinged_wrapper` as parameter, just an idea...

Comment: @Peter: Inside a function, you simply can't prevent problems that happened before calling the function. So no need to worry.

Comment: @Galik Then cue a template solution with appropriate traits! Needs a bit of thought as template functions are quite low in the overload resolution pecking order.

Answer (score 0):

Add an overload for `ptrdiff_t`, which is the closest corresponding signed type. At runtime, check if this overload got a negative value. If so, complain to the user, else cast the checked value to `size_t` and call the original.